# Program doesn't produce any error or output

Tags: python

I have the following Python program:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import sys   

    class MyXmlParser(object):

        def __init__(self, users):
            self.doc  = ET.parse("users.xml")
            self.root = self.doc.getroot()

        def do_something(self, output = sys.stdout):
            root_new  = ET.Element("users") 
            for child in self.root:
                username             = child.attrib['username']
                password             = child.attrib['password']   
                # create "user" here
                user    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "user") 
                user.set("username",username)               
                user.set("password",password) 
                # checking attribute - skip KeyError
                try:
                    remote_access   = child.attrib['remote_access']
                    user.set("remote_access", remote_access) 
                except KeyError:
                    pass

                for g in child.findall("group"):
                    # create "group" here
                    group     = ET.SubElement(user,"group")  
                    if g.text != "lion":
                        group.text = g.text 
            tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
            tree.write(output)
if __name__ =='main':
    parser = MyXmlParser()
    parser.do_something()
```

And this is my xml :

```
<users>
<user username="admin"  password="admin" remote_access="yes"></user>
<user username="private_user1" password="user1" ><group>group1</group><group>group2</group></user>
<user username="private_user2" fullname="user2" password="user2"><group>group1</group><group>group2</group></user>
</users>
```

I can't find any mistake in this program. It should output some xml. But presently it's not giving any error or output. I expected some xml as output :( Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: anything is missed from this ? main method ? any example pls

Comment: you're not actually instantiating your class or calling `do_something` method. This is just a definition.

Comment: ok i got it but any example will help me more :)

Comment: you should create a main part (**if __name__==" __main__ ":**) where you instantiate the object and call the do_something method. Also, you have an init with a parameter named users that you're not using anywhere. Mind this too when trying for errors

Comment: For starters, add `MyXmlParser().do_something()` at the bottom of your script. Then search around for a tutorial on classes (in Python), eg http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: Looking at the init method at the line: self.root = doc.getroot(), the where is the reference to doc? should it maybe be self.doc.getroot() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your `MyXmlParser` class constructor to:

```
    def __init__(self, users=None):
        self.doc = ET.parse("users.xml")
        self.root = self.doc.getroot()
```

and added this after the class definition:

```
if __name__==" __main_ ":
    parser = MyXmlParser()
    parser.do_something()
```

and got this one line of output:

```
<users><user password="admin" remote_access="yes" username="admin" /><user password="user1" username="private_user1"><group>group1</group><group>group2</group></user><user password="user2" username="private_user2"><group>group1</group><group>group2</group></user></users>
```

Comment: After class definition : ? Exactly where it is ? +1 point for "self.root = self.doc.getroot()" thanks. but still its same for me :(

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake ;) , any how thanks a lot, god bless you. :)

Comment: i missed if __name__ =='__main__':

Comment: BTW, I also changed the second argument to `users=None` because it wasn't referenced within `__init__()` anyway.

Comment: @SRquery: Why the sudden unaccept?

Comment: :( by mistake...its a perfect answer, how can i remove this ?